# how to check if NERDTree is open in vimscript?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I tried to write a command to save session compatible with NERDTree, I need to check if the NERDTree is open, I can't find any info though Google.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and what didn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NERDTree internally stores the name of its scratch buffer (that represents the tree contents in Vim) in a tab-local variable. With `bufwinnr()`, you can ask Vim whether the buffer is currently loaded in a window.

I use the following function to check for the NERDTree existence (in the current tab page; if you need this globally, you'd have to iterate over all tabs with `gettabvar()`).

```
function! IsNerdTreeEnabled()
    return exists('t:NERDTreeBufName') && bufwinnr(t:NERDTreeBufName) != -1
endfunction
```

Answer (score 12):

The NERDTree plugin itself already has a function for this purpose.

```
g:NERDTree.IsOpen()
```

Example:

```
if exists("g:NERDTree") && g:NERDTree.IsOpen()
    ....
endif
```